Handling Underrepresented Gender Categories in SEM
I’m including gender as a covariate in my SEM. My data consists of 1,078 cases
with 29 "Prefer not to say" and 8 "Diverse gender".
I’ve treated "Prefer not to say" as NA. However, the diverse gender group is very small, which could lead to instability. Should I:

Treat these cases as NA as well?
Exclude them entirely and report findings qualitatively?
Use another approach?

Treating as NA" would involve using all other variables of the individuals but treating their gender as missing and handling them by maximum likelihood.
Unfortunately I could not find any literature or recommendations online. How do you typically handle such cases? Thanks!

What does 'treating as NA' involve? Modelling as a distinct category level? Imputing the value? ...

"Treating as NA" would involve using all other variables of the individuals but treating their gender als missing and handling them by maximum likelihood.
